Cognito userpool + identiy pool + IOT Core
For our webAPI and web-application we use cognito with userpools. We have a custom authentication logic so receiving a token is implemented in our own restAPI, which we developed in AWS Lambda with nodeJS. We want to use this same token to login into IOT core, and according documentation this should be possible with cognito and identiy pools.
I've created an identity pool, created a role to connect/subscribe to IOTCore with your username and try to login with a regular MQTT client with username/password as username and the jwt token (IdToken) received by the cognito userpool.
However, I am unable to login. Neither do I see any identities in the identity pool (Total identities: 0). I'm not sure if this is set up correctly,. I've setup the identity provider to the user pool in the identity pool, but it seems it's not connected or something. Do I need to add an extra step in my login flow to add the JWT token to the identity pool aswell?
I've tried reading different implementations, but it seems I'm missing a step to add the user login to the identity pool. I guess this should be done in the login flow in our rest-api but I can't find a way to do this.
